# Determine the image of the lines $Re(z) = a$ and $ℑ(z) = b$ under the transformation $f(z) = 1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, transformation

I am unsure of how to solve the following question. I provided my attempt however I am doubtful that it is correct.

Determine the image of the lines $Re(z) = a$ and $ℑ(z) = b$ under the transformation
$f(z) = \frac 1 z$

My attempt: $z=x+iy$, but if $Re(z)=a$ therefore $z=a+iy$

since $f(z)=\frac 1 z$, we obtain $\frac 1 {a+iy}$

Multiplying the fraction by its complex conjugate we obtain $\frac {a-iy} {a^2+y^2}$

$f(z)= u(a,y)+iv(a,y)$

where $u(a,y)= \frac a {a^2+y^2}$ and $v(a,y)= \frac {-y} {a^2+y^2}$

Unsure of: $u=\frac {-a}{y}.v$ so $y=\frac{-a.v}{u}$

Thus, $u^2+v^2-\frac u a =0$

So it forms a circle of radius $\sqrt \frac u a$ centered at $(\frac u a , 0)$

Would i use the same method for $ℑ(z) = b$ or should I have done them as a combination to begin with?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$u^2+v^2-\frac{u}{a} = u^2 - 2\cdot u \cdot\frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{4a^2} + v^2 - \frac{1}{4a^2} = \\= \left(u - \frac{1}{2a}\right)^2 + v^2 - \frac{1}{4a^2},$$
thus the equation of the image of the line $\operatorname{Re}(z)=a$ is
$$\left(u - \frac{1}{2a}\right)^2 + v^2 = \frac{1}{4a^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Therefore it is again a circle but with radius $\frac 1 {2a}$ and is centered at $(\frac 1 {2a} , 0)$

Comment: Do I use the same method of $Im(z) = b$?

Comment: Yes, you can do it similarly.